# Jenkins Pipeline: How to replace part of a sh command arg with a variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am unsure about some syntax I am putting together for a Jenkins pipeline step where I want to replace part of a command line arg (for a filename) in a shell script with a variable I have defined

```
sh "npx cypress run --config-file cypress/cypress.$e2eEnvironment.json --env $envCredentials || true"
```

I think what I have above will look for a variable `$e2eEnvironment.json` but I dont want that as I need to keep the .json as is in the cli arg. E.g. if I have an $e2eEnvironment value set to `integration` then the value should get built as `cypress/cypress.integration.json`

Can someone guide me here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce the exact name of a variable resolution in string interpolation with `${<varName>}` syntax in Groovy. In your example:

```
sh "npx cypress run --config-file cypress/cypress.${e2eEnvironment}.json --env $envCredentials || true"
```

will resolve to:

```
sh "npx cypress run --config-file cypress/cypress.integration.json --env $envCredentials || true"
```

as desired, instead of resolving the assigned value for a variable name `e2eEnvironment.json`.